# Why didn't Sublime install as other application?

Tags: software-installation, sublime-text

I downloaded Sublime (unfortunately I don't remember exactly how I did so) but I don't understand why it looks strange. The application is in my Downloads folder and in there I see a bunch of files inside.

To run it, I click the one called `sublime_text` but this just feels strange. It doesn't look like a normal application (because I don't start other application this way), nor can I search for it in the Dash Home.

[image: Screenshot of what's inside the folder]

Comment: «Why didn't Sublime install» Just to be precise: applications do not install themselves. You decide which way you download and install applications. Anyway, **all programs** are just folders with a bunch of executable files inside. The fact you see them in the Dash is just added "convenience": the packages contain a few more files that are stored in the right directories, in particular application launchers are in `/usr/share/applications`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you downloaded a tarball of sublime text, which was provided for non-debian Linux distributions.

To install it as deb package use these commands in a Terminal (Open by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
wget -c https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime-text_build-3114_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i sublime-text.deb
```

**Note:** If you're using 32-bit Ubuntu, first command will be

```
https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime-text_build-3114_i386.deb
```

You should now be able to use it like other regular packages without having to open it from extracted folder.